# Can't seem to skip 4th level subdirectory in bash loop

Tags: bash, scripts, backup

I have written a bash script that will loop through the /data directory and backup then encrypt all volumes using duplicity.

We have discovered that one of the applications is generating a ton of large files that we dont need to backup. so I am trying to figure out a method to exclude this sub-directory from the script

```
backup_volume() { TARGET_DEVICE=$1
    for vol in /data/*; do
        VOLUME=$(basename $vol)
        echo "Backing up $VOLUME on $TARGET_DEVICE/$VOLUME"
        duplicity --file-prefix ${VOLUME}_ --full-if-older 1M /data/$VOLUME $TARGET_DEVICE/$VOLUME --allow-source-mismatch
--encrypt-key "Privbackup" --gpg-options "--batch --pinentry-mode loopback --trust-model always" || ERRORS="$ERRORS $vol>$TARGET_DEVICE"
        duplicity --file-prefix ${VOLUME}_ remove-older-than 1M --force --encrypt-key "Privbackup" --gpg-options "--batch --pinentry-mode loopback --trust-model always" $TARGET_DEVICE/$VOLUME || ERRORS="$ERRORS $vol>$TARGET_DEVICE"
done
}
```

I have tried adding things like

```
if [$vol = /data/dir1/dir2/dir3/]; then 
continue 
fi
```

but it doesnt seem to pickup the full relative dir.... help!

Comment: `if [$vol = /data/dir1/dir2/dir3/];` should print an error, because you're missing spaces... [Read this...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/brackets-in-if-condition-why-am-i-getting-syntax-errors-without-whitespace).

Comment: Thanks @pLumo that has now enabled me to skip the particular iteration of that loop. Now I need to figure out how to recurse into a few different levels of directory to exclude the 4th degree!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** consider `--exclude` option from `duplicity`.

---

`/data/*` will expand to all non-hidden files in `/data`, meaning it will output:

```
/data/file1
/data/file2
/data/dir1
/data/dir2
```

**It will not recurse**, so it won't expand to:

```
/data/dir1/file1
/data/dir1/dir2
```

You can try with `printf '%s\n' /data/*`.

If you want it to recurse, use `globstar` and `**`:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
for vol in /data/**; done
    [ "$vol" = "/data/dir1/dir2/dir3" ] && continue
    ...
done

# Unset globstar if you want:
shopt -u globstar
```

---

**Anyhow!** You should rather consider `--exclude` option from `duplicity`.

```
duplicity --exclude /data/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Comment: The challenge with --exclude is that you must define a directory path and since this is a 'for' loop that traverses through /data (which stores data directories for multiple apps in docker containers) i cant define it in the duplicity command. unless there's a way to say "if $vol is /data/dir1/dir2/dir3" then append duplicity with --exclude /data/dir1/dir2/dir3 *ponder*